Use electron-forge's vite,typescript template to open child window in renderer.ts
I am trying to create a desktop app using the electron-forge vite,typescript template.
this:
https://www.electronforge.io/templates/vite-+-typescript

//main.ts

import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
import path from 'path';

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation:false,
    },
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  if (MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL);
  } else {
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, `../renderer/${MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_NAME}/index.html`));
  }

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and import them here.


This is the code for the main.ts generated by the template, but with nodeIntegration set to true and contextIsolation set to false.
Now, in renderer.ts, I want to create a new child window and load subWindow.html in the src folder.
If possible, I want a solution that can be completed within renderer.ts, without using ipc communication, etc.

//renderer.ts

import './index.css';

console.log(' This message is being logged by "renderer.ts", included via Vite');


Here is the file structure.

I have browsed various sites but have not found a simple solution for this environment. is it possible to implement a complete implementation in renderer.ts without using ipc communication? And if it is not possible, what should I do?
